# How to insert whitespaces before and after a word or character?

Tags: java, string

I try to convert strings into better reading ones. Like "SaintPierreandMiquelon" into "SaintPiere and Miquelon" or "SaintVincentandtheGrenadines" into 
"SaintVincent and the Grenadines"

My approach was this:

```
public static String whitespace(String str) {

    String string = str;
    if (string.contains("and")) {

        String[] parts = string.split("and");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1];
        String partres = part1 + " and " + part2;


        if (partres.contains("the")) {
            String[] partl = string.split("the");
            String partl1 = partl[0];
            String partl2 = partl[1];
            String parterg = partl1 + " the " + partl2;
            return parterg;
        } else {
            return partres;
        }
    } else {
        return string;
    } }
```

Which obviously sucks. The output is wrong too. It works for "and" but if theres a "the" in the string too it just works for "the".

Output is for this String: "SerbiaandEuropetheAmerica" --> "SerbiaandEurope the America"

Comment: How do you expect the program to detect where to split the string?

Comment: And `"ampersand"` will be splitted into `"ampers and"`?

Comment: Why 'SaintVincentandtheGrenadines' is 'Saint Vincent...' but 'SaintPierreandMiquelon' is 'SaintPiere...'?

Comment: Have you thought about Finl and?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Or even better, `Holl and`. @bastel String class has `replaceAll` method, but your approach wouldn't work as expected I'm afraid, you'll need a dictionary and even then it would be difficult.

Comment: My dataset is only country names concatinated with "and", "the" and ","

Comment: What about the situation that @Timekiller explained? all the countries ending with *land* would get split.

Comment: @bastel In that case it's a lot easier to create a map of all the possible countries like this: `map.put( "SaintVincentandtheGrenadines", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" );` and then look up your input strings in the map.

Comment: By the way, Holland is the name of a region, not a country. The country is officially called **Nertherl and S**.

Comment: Also, what about "of"? UnitedStatesofAmerica, DemocraticRepublicoftheCongo...

Comment: Your last edit has completely change the nature of the original question

Comment: I know i've done a mistake in the original post. That map solution sounds reasonable but i would have to do it for 229 countrys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String str = "SerbiaandEuropetheAmerica";
str = str.replaceAll("the", " the ");
str = str.replaceAll("and", " and ");
System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

It is the result:

```
str = Serbia and Europe the America
```

Comment: I did an exception for countrys end with land.

Comment: @bastel I don't understand how this is the correct solution? you have originally asked to split **SaintVincent** to **Saint Vincent** how do you achieve it by this coded above? Also why do you consider the other two answers incorrect?

Comment: Do not forget to do str = str.replaceAll("--", "-"), i.e. remove two consequtive spaces that can be created: "theand" -> "-the--and- " (spaces replaced by minus due to stupid autoformating)

Answer (score 1):

On a second thought, there's a regexp solution if following is true:

1) Every word of every country name is Initcap

2) When two countries are nearby in your string, they're divided either by "," (you mentioned it in comments) or by "and", so there's no strings like "HollandFrance" or "HollandtheAmerica":

```
String str = "Serbia,FinlandandHolland,theAmerica";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("([A-Z]|and|the)(?!and|,|$)", " $1").trim());
```

It's still a makeshift solution, so examine the results carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem and linked to the fact that in your **second** condition "**if**" you **split** on the **string** **instead** of the **partres** variable.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using replace, like in the following manner:

```
string.replace("the", " the ");
string.replace("and", " and ");
string.replace("  ", " ");
```

Comment: how do you expect to split *SaintVincent* to *Saint Vincent*

Comment: I do not expect that, since the behaviour you stated is explicitly not wanted by the person who is questioning.
Quote: "SaintVincentandtheGrenadines" into "SaintVincent and the Grenadines"

Comment: I wonder who gave you credits for your misunderstanding of the question.

Comment: kindly look at the edits of the question. You would understand that this is not a misunderstanding. Also in my last comment to the question I wanted to point that only.

Comment: this is the original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34337505/1 . Kindly clear your misunderstanding

Comment: I did understand the question correctly from the beginning as far as I can see. This does not hold for you. In fact, you got the question wrong.